# How can I make a ViewModel instance alive in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

In my app, there is a singleton instance, `AppSetting`, which is used in the entire views and models. AppSetting has a variable, `userName`.

```
class AppSetting: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = AppSetting()
    private init() { }

    @Published var userName: String = ""
}
```

ParentView prints `userName` when it is not empty. At first, it is empty.

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @State var isChildViewPresented = false
    @ObservedObject var appSetting = AppSetting.shared

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            VStack {
                Button(action: { self.isChildViewPresented = true }) {
                    Text("Show ChildView")
                }

                if !appSetting.userName.isEmpty { // <--- HERE!!!
                    Text("\(appSetting.userName)")
                }
            }

            if isChildViewPresented {
                ChildView(isPresented: $isChildViewPresented)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When a user taps the button, `userName` will be set.

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @ObservedObject var childModel = ChildModel()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            VStack {
                Button(action: { self.childModel.setUserName() }) { // <--- TAP BUTTON HERE!!!
                    Text("setUserName")
                }

                Button(action: { self.isPresented = false }) {
                    Text("Close")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class ChildModel: ObservableObject {
    init() { print("init") }
    deinit { print("deinit") }

    func setUserName() {
        AppSetting.shared.userName = "StackOverflow" // <--- SET userName HERE!!!
    }
}
```

The problem is when `userName` is set, the instance of `ChildModel` is invalidated. I think when ParentView adds `Text("\(appSetting.userName)")`, it changes its view hierarchy and then it makes SwiftUI delete the old instance of ChildModel and create a new one. Sadly, it gives me tons of bug. In my app, the ChildModel instance must be alive until a user explicitly closes ChildView.

**How can I make the ChildModel instance alive?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible when to de-couple view & view model and inject dependency via constructor

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @ObservedObject var childModel: ChildModel  // don't initialize

    // ... other your code here
```

store model somewhere externally and inject when show child view

```
if isChildViewPresented {
    // inject ref to externally stored ChildModel()
    ChildView(isPresented: $isChildViewPresented, viewModel: childModel)  
}
```